# fnFilter not working on server sided processing

Tags: javascript, php, datatable, zend-framework2

I'm working with DataTables, using server sided pagination and filtering. The global search works well, but I'm trying to do a column search. In each tfoot I have an input or a select, when I change the select or keyup inputs, the plugin start searching but doens't work.

That is javascript code I'm using

```
        var oTable = $('#paginacaoTabela').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": $(location).attr('href'),
        });         

        $("tfoot td").each(function (i) {               
            $(this).on('change', 'select', function () {
                oTable.fnFilter(this.value, i);
            });

            $(this).on('keyup', 'input', function () {
                oTable.fnFilter(this.value, i);
            });                 
        });
```

I'm using Zend Framework 2 to process the searches. 
If you want, you can see the script live here http://protesto21.com.br/usuario/
User: admin, password: p21

Sorry for bad english and thanks.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Is the request sent? What does the request return? What do you expect the request to return? etc.. etc..

Comment: The value is not sended to sSearch parameter in URL. The global filter works well, but this one by column not. When I type something, the server sided script return all data from database